# Can I eval a value in quote?

Tags: quote, eval, backquote

I have a variable say `some-var`, its value is a string. I want to use its *value* in a `quote` expression.

```
'(some-var "some string")
```

The function who is using the above expression reports error because it gets `some-var` literally...not the value.

Any trick to eval `some-var` inside a `quote` expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Don't use quotes at all, as in:

```
(list some-var "some-string")
```

2) Use a backquote. They work like quotes, but part of an expression can be evaluated by using `,` and `,@`. For example:

```
`(,some-var "some-string")
```

Comment: Why I did not think about `list` at the first place...lol! Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to accomplish `'((".*" . "PATH"))`, where "PATH" should be an evaluated expression. I ended up using: `(list (cons ".*" (EXPR)))`.