# What's the difference between ' (quote) and ` (grave accent)

Tags: quote, backquote

I've seen both used to quote symbols and list.
What's the difference between them?
When should I use one or the other?

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/can-i-eval-a-value-in-quote) or [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list) or the [Emacs lisp documentation on quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) and [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote).

Comment: Teach a man to fish: `C-h i`. Then `g elisp RET`. Then `g quot` and you will see the relevant doc. Although, you would need basic setup or you won't get filtered search results.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @TerryTsao: I believe you mean `C-h i m elisp ...` - `g` does not work at the top level at least IME.

Comment: @NickD Indeed. I found out a while later using `emacs -Q`. By then I couldn't edit the comment. My setting would invoke `ivy` at the top level, but not for everybody. :-(

Comment: It would be `g (elisp)` to jump to the elisp manual, rather than `g elisp`.  That or `d m elisp` are both slightly more reliable alternatives than just `m elisp` (as they make no assumptions about what the user was reading previously).  You could also jump directly to the node in question within that manual with `g (elisp)Quoting RET`

Comment: In this instance I'd suggest making use of the manual's index: `M-x elisp-index-search RET \` RET` -- or use `i` or `I` from inside the info reader.

Comment: @phils Can people with higher reputations edit other people's comments? I cannot edit my comments now.

Comment: Maybe by a moderator?  AFAIK comments aren't version-controlled the way that questions and answers are, so allowing others to edit them would be problematic in general.  Once the 5min threshold has passed, all you can do is delete them.

Comment: After 5 mins, I cannot edit my comments, so when desperate, I copy the content, delete the comment and add a new comment, pasting in the old contents and editing appropriately. But I very rarely do that, only when I think the comment is really wrong or misleading, or missing an important point. The most important point about your comment however is: Use Info *in* emacs to look up things - and that's absolutely spot-on.

Comment: I can't believe this silly question got so many comments XD